# what is the format specifier for atomic<uint64_t> datatype in C++?

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu

I am using Ubuntu virtual box and writing a project in C++.
I am unable to put a format specifier for atomic<uint64_t> datatype in C++.

Comment: Format specifier? You mean for `printf` etc?

Comment: `atomic<uint64_t>` looks like a C++ type rather than C.

Comment: In c, atomic types look like this: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/atomic

Comment: Please show us a concrete example of what you are trying to do, and tell us in which way it does not work.

Comment: Hi @Hulk - yes it is for printf and I am using C++

Comment: its %llu, same as C

Comment: @secretsquirrel `llu` is for `long long unsigned int`, as its name implies. This may or may not be the same as `uint64_t`. Using one for the other is a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.load()` to get `uint64_t` out of the atomic, then print it as a regular `uint64_t` using `PRIu64`:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <cinttypes>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    std::atomic<std::uint64_t> x = 42;
    std::printf("x = %" PRIu64 "\n", x.load());
}
```